# Let $u_1=[3,−1,2]$ and $u_2=[2,0,1]$. Find all vectors $v=[x,y,z]$such that $u_1⋅v=0$ and $u_2⋅v=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $u_1=[3,−1,2]$ and $u_2=[2,0,1]$. Find all vectors $v=[x,y,z]$such that $u_1⋅v=0$ and $u_2⋅v=0$

So for this question i would generally just do the dot product between the two and get the answer of 5, but for this questions solution it looks like this

The conditions are $u_1 · v = 0$ and $u_2 · v = 0$, yielding equations

$$3x − y + 2z = 0$$
$$2x + z = 0$$

The solutions are $x = −t$, $y = t$, $z = 2t$, so $v = t[-1,1,2]$

I'm really confused about the solution. I understand the concept of putting into a linear equation but when they just start assigning $x = −t$, $y = t$, $z = 2t$, and so on i just get completely lost. How do they come about this solution?

Comment: The dot product condition is part of the question.  I suggest editing so that this appears earlier.

Comment: I don't get what you mean it looks fine.

Comment: What Michael Burr is pointing out is that "find all vectors $v=[x,y,z]$ such that $u_1=[3,−1,2]$, $u_2=[2,0,1]$" doesn't actually make any sense. I'm guessing you mean: "Let $u_1=[3,−1,2]$ and $u_2=[2,0,1]$. Find all vectors $v=[x,y,z]$ such that $u_1\cdot v=0$ and $u_2\cdot v=0$." Editing the question in this way makes it easier for people to know what problem to help you with.

Comment: @GregMartin Edited it thanks

Comment: Better! Now, you have a system of two linear equations in three variables, and you're wondering how they got the solution they got. In general, how do you use linear algebra to solve a system of linear equations?

Answer (score 0):

the idea behind this is that you are searching for all the vectors that have a specific properties, now you have 3 variables and 2 equations so instead of solving them let's try to represent each one of the variables by a fourth variable and a third equation, for example:
$$
\begin{cases}
3x-y+2z=0
\\[2ex]
2x+z=0
\\[2ex]
t=-x
\end{cases}
$$

now try to represent each of the variables with $t$, solve this equation with $t$ as free variable. You will get the next vector:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-t\\
t\\
2t
\end{pmatrix}\implies
t
\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
1\\
2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

now this expression is true for all $t$, this is basicly all the vectors that will answer your equation, the answer you searched for